# How to get query param and fetch() in load() for static pages in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a vanilla JavaScript page that I'm converting to Svelte.

In Svelte, when a page is opened, how do I get the query string and fetch some API based on that? E.g. `/static-page?product=FOO`.

My current code:

```js
export async function load({fetch, url}) {
    const productCode = url.searchParams.get('product') || 'XXX';
    const endpoint = `/products/${productCode}`;
    const res = await fetch(endpoint);

    return await res.json();
}
```

It works, but fails to build using `adapter-static`. I heard that I can use `onMount`:

```js
let productCode;

onMount(() => {
    productCode = $page.url.searchParams.get('product') || 'XXX';
});
```

But `productCode` is `undefined` in `load()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use a variable whose value is set in `onMount()` inside `load()`.

- `adapter-static` runs `load()` at build-time.
- `onMount()` is run later at run-time.
- Even without `adapter-static`, `load()` runs before `onMount()`.

So you need to call your API from `onMount()` (and modify the DOM as needed from `onMount()`).

---

An alternative solution may be to use a [URL param](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data-params) instead of a query string (like: `/static-page/[product]/` that is accessed via `/static-page/FOO/`). `load()` has access to URL params, but you should point the pre-renderer to all the possible `product`s unless it is OK to dynamically render products unknown at build-time. (The [example from the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender) is "prerender your most recent/popular content but server-render the long tail").

Note this alternative solution requires using a different adapter with the `prerender` option instead of `adapter-static`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the `onMount` approach, but what's the canonical way in Svlete to make the data available on the page? E.g. in `load` it's simply returned.

Comment: Well, in SvelteKit `load()` *is* the canonical way. Although static rendering is supported, the main use-case is serverless rendering (like vercel-adapter) with optional progressive enhancement. @wiradikusuma

Answer (score 2):

If you want static pages, then you will want to run this code on the client at runtime. This means you do not want it in the `load` function.

In the script tags of the page you want this functionality on, create a function for fetching the data, and call the function in the `onMount`.

Something like below

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let products = [];
    
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const productCode = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('product') || 'XXX';
      const endpoint = `/products/${productCode}`;
      const res = await fetch(endpoint);
      return await res.json();
  }

    onMount(()=>{
        products = fetchProducts();
    })
</script>

{#each products as product}
    <div>{product.name}</div>
{/each}
```